# Click on a hyperlink using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hyperlink

I am trying to automate our dirsync process. Basically I need to log in to the site, search for the user, and click the edit to change three settings, but for some reason I can't make PowerShell click the Edit. `<a href="/User/Details` or `><a href="/User/Edit/` never changes, but the rest changes depending on the user.

```
    <td>domain.com.com/OU/lastname, firstname</td>
    <td>username</td>
    <td>firstname</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Pinar</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>00334764</td>
    <td>8/1/2012 5:53:45 PM</td>
    <td><a href="/User/Details/sajskjdf-ajsjkf-asddd">Details</a></td>
    <td><a href="/User/Edit/sajskjdf-ajsjkf-asddd">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#login to site
$url = "https://website"
$username = 'username'
$password = read-host "password"
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($url);

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
}

$ie.Document.getElementById("username").value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementById("Password").value = $password
$go = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName(‘button’) | where-object {$_.type -eq ‘submit’}
$go.click()

while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}

# Enter the username you want to edit
$logonname=read-host "logonname"
$ie.Document.getElementById("query").value = $logonname
$go2 = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName(‘button’) | where-object {$_.type -eq ‘submit’}
$go2.click()

while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}

# I can't make this part work :(
$go3 = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName(‘A’)
$yt = $go3 | where-object {$_.innerText -eq '/Edit/User/'}
$yt.click()
```

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Is the goal to automate a web browser?  Or to read the HTML from a text file, find all hrefs, and load them?  Are you trying to load them in a browser or simply download their content?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of clicking on a specific link:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate2('http://google.com/')
while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
$links = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')
$yt = $links | where {$_.innerText -eq 'YouTube'}
$yt.click()
```

Comment: Hi Shay,The link changes depending on a user. So this part is always going to be different for each user href="/User/Details/sajskjdf-ajsjkf-asddd">Details

Comment: Shay's code sample checks the link *text*, not the link *reference*. Should both text *and* reference change: how do you identify which link you want to click?

Comment: What makes that link unique? Is it always located ah the same place, like a specific table cell index?

Comment: before this point there is a search box, that is I input the username then this page opens and the link changes for each user.the only part stays the same is <td><a href="/User/Details/ and <td><a href="/User/Edit/  anything after that changes. I tried the following but it didn't work. :(       $links = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')
$yt = $links | where {$_.innerText -eq '/User/Edit'}
$yt.click()

Comment: Then you can get the first link in that td if you know its index.

Comment: but when I search for a different user the link is going to change. Is there a way to just search for /user/edit and click on it